# Using Excel table to create new attribute values

Tags: qgis, excel

I have an Excel table with energy values per building age range and per building type. I want to read add a new feature in my point layer with corresponding energy values.

How can I read the Excel values and connect the corresponding building age and building types?

In the first image you see the age ranges and building types with corresponding energy values. In image 2 you see the column "Bouwjaar" which is the building age in Dutch.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need a suitable common ID, then you can link your datasets.

Answer (score 1):

As @Erik mentioned you need a common ID value to link your tables. In case you have that you can save your Excel table as .csv, add this table to Qgis via Data Source Manager - Delimited Text (select No geometry option).
Then choose Processing - Toolbox - Vector general - Join attributes by field value. (Here is a detailed tutorial https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/performing_table_joins.html)

(You can't join tables by Field calculator and it would be unnecessarily complicated with PyQGIS).

Comment: Alternatively one can choose a layer to link to in the layer properties, just below the attribute form dialogue.